# Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium

Not able to run selenium test in React project.

**Error:** The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.

I am using:

- react
- jest
- selenium
- Windows 10

Here is screenshot of path variable on my system:
[image]

Does anyone have some sulution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...
download the file, and...
put it in whatever **PATH** folder the program is referring to / you are using.

Comment: I already do that multiple times, and still does not work.

Comment: Oh well, duplicate! Read the other article.

Comment: Is this really the only answer? We are switching from katalon and creating a new JS based suite. We are going to have 2000+ tests & who knows how they'll be organized & running from different DEV's workspaces... so we're supposted to copy ChromeDriver.exe 50+ times or have every dev install a environment key... but it'll work in the same folder, just not 1 folder up???? That's about the dumbest f'n thing... can anyone explain why they set it up this way?